# Copper coils for nMRI

Tags: electromagnetism, nuclear-physics, resonance, medical-physics

Given the lack of financial efficacy in the medical industry, I was wondering if nuclear magnetic resonance imaging would be possible with a copper/silver coil if the use is short 10 second imaging bursts.
Or is the resistance simply too disruptive for any imaging to occur?

What I had in mind is a very small machine you could stick an arm or leg through for home scanning. Either completely uncooled or a very inexpensive cooling technique like simply running faucet water through it for the brief duration in a bathroom.

Comment: the resolution is directly dependent on the magnetic field intensity, so to have milimeter voxel resolutions you need above a Tesla. You could attain such fields with a copper coil, but the cooling equipment would be just as expensive as the one that would be required for a superconducting magnet, so it (seems to me) like the wrong place to make economic tradeoffs

Comment: A coil field calculator suggests that a 5cm long coil with 250 turns of 6mm2 wire around a 10cm aperture will produce a 1.25T field at 200A. With water seeping through the coil such a field could probably be sustained indefinitely and even if not, imaging could be done in pulses. And mm precision is far from necessary to image a dislocation or foreign object. But what I was looking for is theoretical considerations that would prevent the needed field quality due to the voltage gradient or other effect. Or would it actually work.

Comment: Even if a sweep of the arm took an hour, that's still wildly more convenient if it's a relatively inexpensive home device than being put through the meat grinder that is the medical industry. Done right, a copper coil and some RF power electronics could be quite inexpensive in lean mass production. Why be subject to a scanner that could fit a 250kg american in the palace of greed when you could borrow the neighbors scanner for free. Kickstarter anyone? billion dollar IPO

Answer (score 3):

Several reasons why this is not a great idea: 1) signal to noise ratio scales with field strength: 1.5T is considered a reasonable number although it is possible to get diagnostic images in some situations with lower fields. 2) inductance of coil capable of producing such large fields - try computing the energy stored! 3) during ramping of the magnet, you create eddy currents. Ramp too fast and these currents will heat up other parts of the system (this is a problem even with the gradient coils which ramp in the 10's of milli Teslas per second). 4) need for homogeneous $B_0$ field: all this thermal expansion makes it impossible to shim the magnet to the required homogeneity. 5) Change in geometry because of coil heating: you need field stable to less than a few ppm (although you can tolerate worse if you don't intend to do spectroscopy).

**A few months later...**

I gave this some more thought. A few more problems that I can see (and these are very real):

1. An MRI machine is dangerous - even at low field strengths. It cannot be made into a DIY scanner - if you have any metallic implants, pace makers, jewelry etc you might find yourself trapped, burnt, lacerated... Before people are allowed into an MRI suite (the vicinity of the magnet, let alone in it) they are evaluated to make sure this is safe for them.
2. You don't just need the static B field: you need RF power (to stimulate the signal) and gradients (to create the image) as well. Although advances are being made for "silent" MR for certain exams, MRI machines are typically very loud - another reason why you need them in a shielded room, and why the patient has to wear good quality hearing protection. Again not something to do without supervision. The RF power (128 MHz at 3T, but scales linearly with field strength) also needs shielding, or it will jam all kinds of radio transmission and other equipment (typical power for whole body scanner 10's of kW). The voltages in the gradient run into the kV range, although it might be possible to make this lower (and accept slower / worse resolution imaging)

Having said all that - yes, you can probably make an MRI image with a scanner that has water cooled copper coils and that doesn't take out the electrical grid when you turn it on. You might be able to build it for a lot less than a superconducting scanner - maybe 100k dollars if you just want to scan extremities (arms and legs) - it has been done.

The question is - what then? Under what circumstances does such a scan give information that will help you?

In the end, a medical diagnostic image is intended to give information to a care giver that allows him or her to select the right treatment to make the patient better.  An MRI machine can be a physics curiosity, or a medical tool; but if it is the latter, the information needs to end up in the hands of a doctor, and help this doctor to select a treatment that could not have been chosen without this information.

I don't want to sound pessimistic, but I don't think a kickstarter IPO is going to get you a billion dollars...

See also http://magnetic-resonance.org/ch/03-02.html for some more information

Comment: when an MRI is pounding during scanning, surely nothing is stable to 1ppm? now that you have vented the negative thinking, could you try to apply your knowledge to how it could actually work instead?

Answer (score 2):

It might not actually answer your question, but to throw it into the bowl:

There are some advances in MRI using permanent magnets and even conventional electromagnets with static magnetic fields of about 0.5 Tesla. As far as I know one can do imaging with a reasonable resolution with these devices without the need for extensive cooling. They are used for MRI of the limbs and open MRI when guided intervention is needed. Because they are more easily handled then supercondicting magnets, there are devices that can turn and therefore image the patient for example in an upright position (for spine-imaging in different positions/ different states of weigth). These devices should be much cheaper than conventional MRI, too, although not cheap. But I would think they should be more cost-efficient.

However, everything Floris said is valid for these devices, too, so one will not be able to use them as self-scanners at home.

Comment: Yes there are commercial permanent magnet systems, typically in the 0.2 to 0.5T range. They are indeed cheaper to operate (no need to top up helium, run cryostats...). They are not considered "top of the line". "Reasonable resolution" is a relative term. In regions where it is all that patients have access to, it is no doubt advancing diagnostics: but better health care needs diagnostics _plus_ treatment options...

Comment: "reasonable resolution" is a relative term, indeed. However, the resolution needed is case-dependent. I would not go as far as treating these devices as low-cost-alternative for tomographs with higher fields. Its an alternative if higher field is not needed, or if open devices are needed, e.g. for performing a guided biopsy.